# css changes work when inspector console is open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

im using firefox and chrome and my css changes for the nav only take effect when the inspector console is open as seen below:

without console open:

[image]

with console open:

[image]

ignore the hover effect, but if you look at the first menu item(actual 3rd) it has moved up slightly to be more inline with the others.

my code is:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav container">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">index</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="drop-menu"><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li class="drop-menu"><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Air Conditioning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ventilation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Refrigeration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-height:1199px)  {


.navbar-nav li:nth-child(3) a{
    padding-top:19px !important;
}
```

}

Comment: can u provide fiddle link?

Comment: When you open the console you reduce the size of the viewport. This makes the condition `max-height:1199px` true and the media query starts applying. The behaviour appears to be exactly what you should be expecting.

Comment: its the max height that is the problem, its meant to be max width.  such a silly mistake, but ive been working on this for so long i needed fresh pair of eyes.  thank you!

Comment: Good catch Quentin, Great!